# Arnold Trivium 49 : $ \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Calculate : $$ \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}.$$

---

If you find it too easy, then just post hints.

Comment: How are you defining the branch of the square root? It looks like there may be some issue with getting a single-valued branch, but I can't tell.

Comment: It is stated like this, I'm not getting it too.

Comment: Also, I think you can just consider this as the integral of $dz/\sqrt{1+z}$ over the circle of radius $2^{10}$, with the circle traversed $10$ times.

Comment: I guess you have to do one of those keyhole arguments in order to deal with the branch cut. It doesn't seem like a well-posed problem, though.

Comment: Take the principal branch for $z=2$ and then analytically continue, it's not a problem. Now hints: there is an *even* number of square root singularities of the integrand on the unit circle, and there are no other singularities (in particular, at infinity).

Comment: @O.L. Would you mind posting a solution? I'm not sure why singularities at infinity are relevant. Doesn't the residue theorem only care about singularities in the contour?

Comment: @Potato Instead of shrinking contour of integration (here it would give $5$ integrals around the branch cuts) one can expand it to $\infty$. Or you can think of this as shrinking the contour by the other side of the Riemann sphere, after the change of variables $z=1/\tilde{z}$. And since in terms of this new variable we have $$\oint_{|\tilde{z}|=1/2}\frac{\tilde{z}^3d\tilde{z}}{\sqrt{1+\tilde{z}^{10}}}$$ the answer is immediate.

Comment: @Potato I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choosing the squareroot which is positive on the positive real axis we have
$${1\over\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}={1\over z^5}(1+z^{-10})^{-1/2}={1\over z^5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-1/2\choose k}z^{-10k}\ ,$$
where the binomial series converges uniformly on $\partial D_2$. Therefore
$$J:=\int_{\partial D_2}{dz\over\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-1/2\choose k}\int_{\partial D_2}z^{-10k-5}\ dz\ .$$
As $-10k-5\ne-1$ for all $k\geq0$ all summands on the right hand side are zero. It follows that $J=0$.

Answer (score 5):

First of all to make all things well-defined, we have to fix the branch of the square root. It will be chosen so that for real $z>0$ we have $\sqrt{1+z^{10}}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Next let us analyze the singularities of the integrand in the complex $z$-plane. They are given by $10$ square root branch points on the unit circle, of the form $z_k=\exp\frac{i\pi(1+2k)}{10}$, $k=0,\ldots,9$. We can choose the branch cuts as shown on the figure below.

Now let us make the change of variables $z=1/s$. The contour of integration will change the orientation which will compensate the minus sign in $dz=-ds/s^2$, and the integral itself becomes
$$I=\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}=\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z^5\sqrt{1+z^{-10}}}
=\oint_{|s|=\frac12}\frac{s^3ds}{\sqrt{1+s^{10}}},$$
where all contours are oriented counterclockwise. Note that in the complex $s$-plane all branch cuts are outside the integration contour. Further, the point $s=0$ (which corresponds to $z=\infty$) is not a pole. Therefore we can shrink the contour in the $s$-plane and conclude that $I=0$. In terms of variable $z$, that would correspond to expanding the contour to infinity.

[image]

Comment: I choose the branch of $\log(1+z^{10})$ such that $0 < \arg(1+z^{10}) \le 2 \pi$.  Then the cuts are inside of the unit circle. What choice leads to the cuts being on the unit circle?

Comment: @RandomVariable One has a lot of freedom in the choice of the cuts, this is a matter of convention. We could make them curly, make some of them go to infinity, etc. To simplify the argument, however, it is better to have them inside the circle $|z|=2$. My choice to put them on the circle $|z|=1$ was determined by aestetic reasons.

Comment: I know.  But choosing the above branch is how I would argue that there is no branch point at infinity.

Comment: @RandomVariable To choose a branch, one has to 1) specify the value of the function at some point and 2) say where the branch cuts are. So far I don't understand where they are in what you have written (can you specify this?), and also whether $\arg(1+z^{10})\in(0,2\pi]$ is consistent at all.

Comment: If you make cuts everywhere on the complex plane where $1+z^{10}$ is real and positive, then the branch of $\log(1+z^{10})$ where $0 < \arg(1+z^{10}) \le 2 \pi $ is single-valued and analytic. The function $1+z^{10}$ is real and positive along 5 diameters of the unit circle.

Comment: @RandomVariable Sorry, I don't understand your comment. $\log$ has nothing to do with this problem. The branch cuts start at branch point and end at branch points (furthermore, there is a cut emanating from *every* branch point), whereas you propose e.g. to introduce a cut from $-1$ to $1$. This doesn't make sense to me, though maybe I misunderstand something in the above.

Comment: I don't know why you would say that the $\log$ function has nothing to do with it.  The reason $\sqrt{1+z^{10}} = \exp \Big( \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+z^{10}) \Big)$ is multivalued is because $\ln(1+z^{10})$ is multivalued. And I somehow overlooked that $1+z^{10}$ is real and positive along the real axis. So the entire real axis would need to be cut out.  That's definitely not going to work. How did you come to the conclusion that there is no branch point at infinity?

Comment: @RandomVariable Exponentiating is (imo) a bit misleading here precisely because it becomes more difficult to understand what is going on at infinity. The function $\sqrt{1+z^{10}}$ has no branch point there because it can be represented by a Laurent series: $\sqrt{1+z^{10}}=z^5\sqrt{1+z^{-10}}=z^5(1+\frac12 z^{-10}+\ldots)$. This would not be the case for $\sqrt{1+z^{9}}$, for instance. But from the point of view of the logarithm, the two cases are not that different.

Comment: I always think of a branch of $z^{a}$ (where $a$ is not an integer) as corresponding to a branch for $\log(z)$.  But is there something invalid about the branch of $\sqrt{1+z^{10}}$ where $0 < \arg(1+z^{10}) \le 2 \pi$? The branch where $-\pi < \arg(1+z^{10}) \le \pi$ would necessitate outward radial cuts from each branch point since that's where $1+z^{10}$ is negative and real. I'm basically following what is done in Ahlfors textbook.  I know it's theoretically possible to get the cuts along the unit circle, but then the function would need to be defined in some strange way.

Comment: @RandomVariable The problem is you will not be able to choose $0<\arg(1+z^{10})< 2\pi$ globally. You can do this, however, in the vicinity of each of the ten branch points - this seems to correspond to the choice of radial branch cuts going to infinity.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)
&=\log(1025)+\sum_{k=0}^9\int_2^z\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w-\xi^{2k+1}}\\
&=\log(1025)+\int_2^z\frac{10w^9\,\mathrm{d}w}{1+w^{10}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where $\xi=e^{\pi i/10}$ is a primitive $20^\text{th}$ root of $1$.

The residue at each singularity of the integrand is $1$. Thus, the integral over a path which circles all $10$ singularities, is $20\pi i$. This means that $g=e^{-f/2}$ is well-defined over any path that encompasses all of the singularities since $e^{-10\pi i}=1$. Therefore, define $g$ by integrating $(1)$ over any path that does not pass inside the unit circle.

From $(1)$,
$$
f'(z)=\frac{10z^9}{1+z^{10}}\tag{2}
$$
Thus, $f(z)$ is locally $\log\left(1+z^{10}\right)$. Therefore, since $g(2)=\frac1{\sqrt{1025}}$, we have
$$
g(z)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}\tag{3}
$$
is well defined and analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ outside the unit circle.

Now, that we have that $\frac1{\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}$ is analytic outside the unit circle, it should be simple to compute
$$
\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}\tag{4}
$$
**Hint:** consider increasing the radius of the circle of integration to $\infty$.

**Hint:** The difference of the large counter-clockwise circular path and the small counter-clockwise circular path is the path below, which encloses the colored C-shaped region. Note that the subtracted path, the small circle, is in the opposite direction from the small counter-clockwise circular path.

$\hspace{4.9cm}$[image]

The integral along the paths connecting the circular paths cancel each other out since they are along the same points in opposite directions.

Thus, the integral along the large counter-clockwise circular path equals the integral along the small counter-clockwise circular path since the function is analytic in the colored region.

The absolute value of $\frac1{\sqrt{1+z^{10}}}$ over the outer path is less than $\frac1{\sqrt{r^{10}-1}}\sim\frac1{r^5}$ and the path is $2\pi r$ long, so the integral over the outer path is $O\left(\frac1{r^4}\right)\to0$.

Comment: Tnx, Since it is analytic outside the unit circle, the integral equals zero outside the unit circle.
How do I proceed ?

Comment: @aziiri: see my second hint.